# On Click Image Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, onclick

I made a script with an image and a javascript function but it doesn't work. It should redirect to www.moseso.de when you click the image. What's wrong with it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hallo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="test.jpg" onclick="func" />
        <script>
            function func() {
                window.location="www.moseso.de"
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick="func();"` You can think that as `img.onclick = function(){ ...the statements ...};` so you need to call it.

Comment: Thank you :D Didn't know that it is so easy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try setting:

```
onclick="func();"
```

also close the statement:

```
window.location="www.moseso.de";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<img src="test.jpg" alt="" class="img.my_clickable_image" />


<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('my_clickable_image').click(function() {
           window.location.href = www.moseco.de';
       });
   });
</script>
```